# How to define the result of QRcode::png() as a variable

Tags: php

I have a code which generates a barcode and saves it into a folder as a PNG image. I want to merge the PNG file on top of a JPEG image using `imagecopyresampled()` function. The PNG image generates using following line:

```
QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
```

I tried to define the `$png` image as `$png = QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);`, but it's not working. Would you please let me know how to define the `$png` variable such that it's not null or string as a resource in `imagecopyresampled()` function.

Below is the code:

```
    include "/applications/AMPPS/www/files/phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
    include "/applications/AMPPS/www/files/phpqrcode/qrconfig.php";

    $codeContents = rand(1000000, 9999999); 

    // we need to generate filename somehow,  
    // with md5 or with database ID used to obtains $codeContents... 
    $fileName = '005_file_'.md5($codeContents).'.png'; 

    $pngAbsoluteFilePath = '/applications/AMPPS/www/files/barcodes/'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$fileName; 

    // generating 
    if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
            QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath); 
            echo 'File generated!'; 
            echo '<hr />'; 
        } else { 
            echo 'File already generated! We can use this cached file to speed up site on common codes!'; 
            echo '<hr />'; 
        }
```

Comment: Does `QRcode::png()` return anything? If so, `$png = QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);` should work.

Comment: Could you show us the content of the png function ?

Comment: since we know nothing about how this QRcode class works, we can't really help you. You've provided **NO** details about what it returns, or how it operates internally.

Comment: The title implies the question is going to be generically about `::`, but it's not: it's about what some specific library function does.

Comment: If this is the PHPQRCode library, there is nothing returned from that static method. You will probably need to pass `$pngAbsoluteFilePath` to your other method so it can read it from there.

Comment: Looks like you're using [this library](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). From the examples, it doesn't look like it provides a return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the docs, it seems that

```
QRcode::png("code data", $pathToFile);
```

creates the file and returns nothing, while

```
QRcode::png("code data");
```

outputs it directly, so if you want to save it to a variable you could do:

```
ob_start();
QRcode::png("code data");
$png = ob_end_clean();
```

that is, you start an output buffer, write the PNG to it, then get it in the variable and clean it.

Comment: thanks Mattheo, I used your code as `ob_start(); QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
$png = ob_end_clean();`, it generates the image file in a folder, but when I echo `filesize($png)`, it echos this error `Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for 1 in `, any help is appreciated,

Comment: You might notice I did **not** pass the second argument to the function, so you shouldn't do it too. It should be just `ob_start(); QRcode::png($codeContents); $png = ob_end_clean();`

Comment: how can I save the file into a folder then?

Comment: Once you have the QR code in `$png`, you can do whatever you like with it, for example, `file_put_contents($pathToFile, $png)`, but if that is what you want, why would you need to save it to a variable first?

Comment: gotcha, I want to write the barcode on top of a JPEG image using `imagecopyresampled()`, can I write `$png` on top of my JPEG images without saving them separately?

Comment: I think you should save your QR code to a PNG, then load it with `imagecreatefrompng` and then manipulate it as you wish and save it back as jpeg.

Comment: @JakeGould, could you please give an example/hint how to apply the GD library for this case?

Comment: Having tested the QRcode, it seems to return nothing. To be sure that the file was created, you can try the if(file_exists($fullFileName-with-path)). This will return either true or false, then you can return the file-name if successful to be used elsewhere (fully or just the name, and append the full path accordingly). Comment used as the topic is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** It seems like `imagecreatefrompng` strictly needs to load a file from somewhere & cannot act as a resource. But leaving this answer up here for refernce since there are other specifics addressed here.

Assuming the output of `QRcode::png(…)` is a PNG—you are using [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/), correct?—why not use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)?

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng(QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath));
```

But looking at the documentation for [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/):

> - QRcode::png('code data text', 'filename.png'); **// creates file**
> - QRcode::png('some othertext 1234'); **// creates code image and outputs it directly into browser**

So that means your call to `QRcode::png(…)` should exclude the `$pngAbsoluteFilePath` like this:

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng(QRcode::png($codeContents));
```

In that way, `QRcode::png($codeContents)` is outputting an image directly, and then `imagecreatefrompng` should capture that & create it as a resource the PHP GD library can use & assign it to `$png`.

Comment: I do not think that `imagecreatefrompng` would "capture" the output of `QRcode::png()`

Comment: @JakeGould, thanks for your answer, I used `$png = imagecreatefrompng(QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath));`, but I got this error `Warning: imagecreatefrompng() [function.imagecreatefrompng]: Filename cannot be empty in /Applications/AMPPS/www/files/file.php on line 16`, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: thank you Jake for taking time, cheers